# Dynamic className together with a fixed class name in a custom component

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a custom component and I want to be able to make it flexible enough to re-use it in other ways. In it's natural form it contains a class `box` and this gives it some native styles. However, if I wanted to reuse this component and alter the styles I would like to cascade another class with the box class it already contains. By simply declaring `className="custom-class"` And it would render as:

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
  <div class="box custom-class">
      Something
  </div>
```

Right now I have something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';

const Box = (props) => (
    <div className='box {props.className}'>
        {props.showTitle &&
            <Row between="xs" className="box-top">
                <span className="box-title">{props.title}</span>
            </Row>
        }
        <Col xs={12} className="box-info">
            {props.content}
        </Col>
        {props.showBottom &&
            <Col xs={12} className="box-bottom">
                {props.bottom}
            </Col>
        }
    </div>
);

export default Box;
```

But this is rendering the following result:

```
  <div class="box {props.className}">
      Something
  </div>
```

It is not parsing the props and changing it for the custom-class. This is how I intend to use it

```
<Box
    showTitle={false}
    showBottom={false}
    className="custom-class"
    content={<MediaStatusBoxContent/>}
/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for this:

```
className={`box ${props.className}`}
```

Or write it like this by using `+`:

```
className={"box " + props.className}
```

When using `{}` that means, its a dynamic value, inside that we can add two strings by using `+`.

Comment: Cool! Litterals didn't work for some reason. But using the + operator did great! Thanks!